# Are IEnumerable collection supported in EF 4.1 for mapping?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I remember this was a problem with previous version of EF. You couldnt make collections as IEnumerable for exposing your methods instead. This is a problem because i don't want someone to directly access the collection.

See this for more info on what i am talking about... [Why does the entity framework need an ICollection for lazy loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866881/why-does-the-entity-framework-need-an-icollection-for-lazy-loading)

So the question is.. are EF 4.1 now support IEnumerable property for mapping relationship ? or is there a solution to this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't support `IEnumerable` because EF internally needs collection which can be assigned and filled by calling `Add`.

Comment: Then is there a solution for the problem where you want to expose your own methods to access the collection instead of using the collection directly ? I believe it need to be public virtual.. but i don't want someone to directly add something to that collection. Why? because maybe i have some logic to be done during the process.