# Cannot convert type System.Data.Entity.DbSet to System.Collections.Generic.ICollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am using `Entity Framework 4.1 code first` in an `MVC 3` app.

I have the following repository:

```
public class BankRepository : IBankRepository
{
     HefContext db = new HefContext();

     public ICollection<Bank> GetAll()
     {
          return db.Banks;
     }
}
```

I get an error when returning db.Banks.  I'm not sure what it means, can someone please help clarify and how to change it so that the error goes away?  The error is:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyProject.Core.DomainObjects.Bank>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MyProject.Core.DomainObjects.Bank>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

What is returned by db.Banks?  An IEnumerable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`db.Banks` is of type [DbSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=VS.103%29.aspx). This class does not implement `ICollection` interface. Change the return type of the method to `IQueryable<Bank>` or `IEnumerable<Bank>`.

```
public class BankRepository : IBankRepository
{
     HefContext db = new HefContext();

     public IQueryable<Bank> GetAll()
     {
          return db.Banks;
     }
}
```

Comment: Most of the examples online use ICollection?  Why is this?

Comment: @Brendan situation has to be different in those examples because your code does not compile.

Answer (score 3):

ICollection is used only as the backing property to support LazyLoading, not as the result of a method. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866881/why-does-the-entity-framework-need-an-icollection-for-lazy-loading) ;)