# Database not being auto-generated properly Entity Framework + Repos Pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, repository-pattern

I've set up Entity Framework Code First with the Generic Repository Pattern.

Here are my models:

```
public interface IEntity {
    int Key { get; set; }
}

public class Product : IEntity {
    public int Key {
        get {
            return ID;
        }
        set {
            ID = value;
        }
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Category { get; set; }

}

public class Category : IEntity {
    public int Key {
        get {
            return ID;
        }
        set {
            ID = value;
        }
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my context that hooks into my generic repo:

```
public class EntitiesContext : DbContext, IDbContext {

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public new IDbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class {
        return base.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

As you can see Product has a IEnumerable of Category. If I were to create a database to match this is would be like so:

**Product**
- ID
- Name
- etc.

**Category**
- ID
- Name
- etc.

**ProductCategories**
- ProductID
- CategoryID

How come when my database is created that there is no joining table?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it is because you are defining the collection as an `IEnumerable<T>`.  I think that Entity Framework needs at least an `ICollection<T>` to make the relationship.  [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866881/why-does-the-entity-framework-need-an-icollection-for-lazy-loading) covers most of it.

So, change this:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> Category { get; set; }
```

To this:

```
public ICollection<Category> Category { get; set; }
```

Further, if you want to lazy load the collection, then also make it virtual:

```
public virtual ICollection<Category> Category { get; set; }
```

Comment: You're right, it worked. I also added public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } to my Category model to create the correct table and relationships. p.s. thanks for the lazy loading tip too :)

Comment: actually, in my View Models (these are my DTOs) should i continue to use Icollection stick with Ienumerable or doesn't it matter?

Comment: I would suggest to use the 'lightest' object possible.  You should be able to set an `IEnumerable` from an `ICollection` since `ICollection` inherits from `IEnumerable`.  So, the choice is up to you.  `ICollection` is more efficient if you are indexing into the collection.