# Does not contain a definition for "Add"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to make the same thing like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383494/mvc-4-many-to-many-relation-and-checkboxes) thread, but I'm getting error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ANIME anime)
{
    var db = new MainDatabaseEntities();
    var newanime = new ANIME
    {
        ID_AN = anime.ID_AN,
        TITLE_OR = anime.TITLE_OR,
        TITLE_EN = anime.TITLE_EN,
        GENRES = new List<GENRES>()
    };

    foreach (var selectedAnime in anime.GENRES.Where(c => c.isSelected))
    {
        var genre = new GENRES { ID_GE = selectedAnime.ID_GE };
        db.GENRES.Attach(genre);
        newanime.GENRES.Add(genre); <--- this is the error line
    }

    db.ANIME.Add(newanime);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

ANIME:

```
public partial class ANIME
{
    public int ID_AN { get; set; }
    public string TITLE_OR { get; set; }
    public string TITLE_EN { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<GENRES> GENRES { get; set; }
}
```

GENRES:

```
public partial class GENRES
{
    public int ID_GE { get; set; }
    public string GENRE { get; set; }
    public bool isSelected { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ANIME> ANIME { get; set; }
}
```

The error is in the line `newanime.GENRES.Add(genre)` in `HttpPost`. I added `using System.Linq` to all models and controllers but it doesn't help. Any ideas how to resolve this?

**EDIT:**

After repairing this a new error arrived. I think it's not related to above one but I don't want to spam unnecessary threads.

Error message:

> The entity or complex type 'MainDatabaseModel.GENRES' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Related code:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var db = new MainDatabaseEntities();
    var viewModel = new ANIME
    {
        GENRES = db.GENRES.Select(c => new GENRES
        {
            ID_GE = c.ID_GE,
            GENRE = c.GENRE,
            isSelected = false
        }).ToList()
    };
    return View(viewModel);       
}
```

Comment: this  post explain more your issue 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210295/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-a-ienumerablet-collection

Comment: @Satpal: there is no `.Add` method in `Linq` either; `IEnumerable`s cannot be modified.

Comment: The question you link to uses the `IEnumerable` for a _view model_. You are using your _Entity Framework entities_ as view models (about which I warned you on an earlier question), you cannot apply that logic as models [require `ICollection` for navigation properties that are one-to-many relations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866881/why-does-the-entity-framework-need-an-icollection-for-lazy-loading). Just change `IEnumerable<T>` to `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: If I can ask, why the odd naming conventions on your properties/classes? In C#, we use Pascal Case for properties, methods and types, and we use camelCase for fields (which are generally not exposed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
public partial class ANIME
{

    public int ID_AN { get; set; }
    public string TITLE_OR { get; set; }
    public string TITLE_EN { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GENRES> GENRES { get; set; } // Use ICollection here
}
```

Comment: Ok, it helped... I had it at the beginning but I changed to IEnumerable because I had some problem with toList() but now it all works. Hmm weird, thanks for help.

Comment: What was your issue with `ToList()`?

Comment: @Placek ICollection<T> is more 'rich' interface than IEnumerable<T>. Check out this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113244/why-use-icollection-and-not-ienumerable-or-listt-on-many-many-one-many-relatio

Comment: New error arrived after repairing this one ;_;. See EDIT in first post.

Comment: @Placek your really need to make a new post - because new answer is quite long. Short answer: you can not construct GENRE in linq to entities, you need to project it to anonymous type and only then construct GENRE objects (by this type you are already in linq to objects). The code: GENRES = db.GENRES.Select(c => new{ ID_GE = c.ID_GE,GENRE = c.GENRE,isSelected = false }).ToList().Select(g => new GENRE {......}).ToList()

Comment: I think this is occurring mainly because he has no ID (by convention!) in GENRES, rather than because you need a proxy type. I do what he has done several times in my code just fine. `field = db.Type.Select(dbType => new fieldType() { ... }).ToList()` will work just fine.

EDIT: woops! no this will not work in linq-to-sql, only in linq-to-objects.

Comment: @DarkWalker The short version of your answer was enough. Thank you very much. I'm setting answer and closing this topic cause I was scolded by CMate ;).

Answer (score 13):

You have an IEnumerable property that you're initialising with a List. The List class implements the IEnumerable interface.

When you are invoking something like this:

```
IEnumerable myList = new List<MyType>();
```

you're saying that you want for your object the features of the `IEnumerable` interface that are also inherited from the `List` class. In this case, the method `Add` isn't part of the IEnumerable interface, because it's a method of the List class only, and you have that exception.

You have then to change the type of your property, from `IEnumerable<YourType>` to `IList<YourType>` (more info about IList [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). If you do so, the exception about `Add` method won't be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerable<>` is just a sequence of items. You can't add items to it and you can't remove items from it. You can query it.

If you need to add items, you will need a collection implementing at least the `ICollection<>` interface or `IList<>` interface.

Good news is that you can use `IEnumerable<>` there like as follows

```
var list = new List<GENRES>();
var newanime = new ANIME
{
    ID_AN = anime.ID_AN,
    TITLE_OR = anime.TITLE_OR,
    TITLE_EN = anime.TITLE_EN,
    GENRES = list
};

list.Add(genre);
```

But this has limited possibilities. You won't be able to add new items once you leave the scope and loose a reference to the local `list` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for your second question is that you cannot (and should not be able to) project onto a mapped entity. You can, however, project onto an annonymous type or on data transfer object.

See this thread:
[The entity cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query)

Also, please do not extend your initial question with a totally new, unrealted one in the future. It makes it hard to follow...