# Entity Framework 6 Fluent Mapping - One to Many Code First

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first-mapping

Given the following SQL tables:

```
EntityGroup:
Id int, (PK)
GroupName nvarchar(100)

Entity:
Id int, (PK)
EntityGroupId int, (FK Non-nullable)
Description nvarchar(100)
```

And the following POCOs

```
  public class Entity
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EntityGroupId { get; set; }    
    public int RefNumber { get; set; }
  }    

  public class EntityGroup
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public virtual IList<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
  }
```

How do I configure the fluent mapping correctly? I want Entity.EntityGroupId to remain as an int rather than an EntityGroup object.

I want to be able to .Include() optionally Include("Entities"). The closest I got is this, but that seems to eager-load all entities even if I dont use .Include("Entities"), which is not the behaviour I want:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityGroup>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Entities);
```

Comment: [Lazy Loading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866881/why-does-the-entity-framework-need-an-icollection-for-lazy-loading)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set off the lazy loading,
you can do this for just a specific unit of work or for all by setting your dbContext Like

```
   dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

or set it in Ctor of your DbContext.

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand it, you want to configure `one-to-many` relationship between `EntityGroup` and `Entity` without navigation property in `Entity` class and using `Entity.EntityGroupId` as a FK. All that with Fluent API.

It's possible, but you have to start the configuration from the class having a  navigation property (`EntityGroup` in your case) because `Has` methods require property accessor while `With` methods have parameterless overloads. As usual, for the last part you will use the `HasForeignKey` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityGroup>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Entities)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.EntityGroupId);
```

But note that EF recognizes the naming convention used in your sample classes (in particular the `EntityGroupId`), so you'll get the same mapping w/o any fluent configuration or data annotations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is [lazy loading](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx) is enabled by default, so it will load the related entities every time you try to get access to them.Two options to solve your issue could be:

1. Disabling lazy loading in your context:

   ```
   public YourContext()
   {
       this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   }
   ```
2. Removing `virtual` from your navigation property, which is one of
   the requirements to work lazy loading and the tracking change:

   ```
   public ICollection<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
   ```

If you want to learn more about the supported ways you can load related entities in EF I suggest you to read this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)